# Trigger variable true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple page with few tabs. The tabs work if disable_function = false otherwise if true then they do not work. The code for the tabs is:

```
var disable_function = false;
jQuery('.tabs a').click(function() {
    if (!disable_function ){
      var ref = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
      jQuery('div.tab_content:not(#' + ref + ')').hide();
      jQuery('#' + ref).fadeIn();
      return false;
    }
});
```

In this page I also have a trigger which I want it, IF the trigger is on then set var disable_function = true;

The code for the trigger is:

```
$('#1').Switch("off", function () {

});
```

I tried by inserting **var disable_function = true;** but it doesn't seem to set it as true. I even tried **set var disable_function = true;**

Im pretty sure this is quite simple but I'm new in jquery.

Thanks alot

Comment: where did you do "var disable_function = true" ? I mean where you set disable_function = true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to learn javascript before jQuery**. I hope i've understood the question anyway this should work:

```
$('#1').Switch("off", function () {
   disable_function = true;
});
```

if you use `var disable_function = true;` you declare a new variable named `disable_function` inside the function scope instead of assign a value to the variable in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to determine what you are asking. Are you just trying to change the value of the `disable_function` variable? If so, you do not need to use `var` again:

```
var disable_function = false;

// later change the value //

disable_function = true;
```